# Spring Integration - Barrier

Tags: spring-integration

I have a thread that uses gateway (void) to send a message to both (pub/sub):

- barrier, to hold the thread during the real execution (requires-reply="true" timeout="XXXX", output-channel="nullChannel"

and to

- splitter which next sends splits as messages to the service activator (direct channel) with poller and a thread executor for the actual processing/execution

How to properly configure handling the exceptions that might be thrown by the executor threads and catch them in the below catch block:

```
try {
    gateway.trigger()  
} catch (ReplyRequiredException e) {
    //fine here
} catch (Throwable t) {
    // catch every exception here... or somehow configure these exceptions to discard the thread that waits on the barrier and throw below business exception
    throw new SomeExecutionFailedException()
}
```

**EDIT**

```
<!--gateway.trigger()—> 
<int:gateway id=“gateway"
             service-interface="com.Gateway"
             default-request-channel=“channel1"
             default-reply-timeout="0"/>

<int:publish-subscribe-channel id=“channel1"/>

<int:splitter input-channel=“channel1" output-channel=“channel2"
              order="1">
    <bean class=“com.Splitter"/>
</int:splitter>

<int:barrier id=“barrier" input-channel=“channel1"
    output-channel="nullChannel"
    correlation-strategy-expression=“'XXX’” <!--hack here-->
    requires-reply="true"
    timeout=“40000"
    order="2">
</int:barrier>

<int:channel id=“channel2">
    <int:queue capacity="30"/>
</int:channel>

<!— actual processing/execution —>
<int:service-activator id=“executionAct" input-channel=“channel2"
                       output-channel=“channel3" ref=“executionService">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="111" time-unit="MILLISECONDS" max-messages-per-poll="22"
                task-executor=“exec"/>
</int:service-activator>

<bean id=“executionService" class=“com.SomeExecService"/>

<bean id=“exec" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="threadFactory" ref=“execFactory"/>
...
    <property name="rejectedExecutionHandler">
        <bean class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id=“execFactory"
      class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.CustomizableThreadFactory">
...
</bean>

<int:channel id=“channel3"/>

<int:chain input-channel=“channel3" output-channel=“channel4">
...
    <int:aggregator
            group-timeout=“30000"
            discard-channel=“discardChannel" release-strategy=“com.ReleaseStrategy"
            send-partial-result-on-expiry="false">
        <bean class="com.Aggregator"/>
    </int:aggregator>
</int:chain>

<int:channel id=“discardChannel”/>

<int:channel id=“channel4"/>

<!— processing done - wake up barrier —>
<int:service-activator id=“barrierReleaseAct" input-channel=“channel4" output-channel="nullChannel">
     <bean class="com.ServiceThatSendsXXXMessageToChannel5ToReleaseBarrier"/>
</int:service-activator>

<int:channel id=“channel5"/>

<int:outbound-channel-adapter channel=“channel5"
                              ref=“barrier" method="trigger"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide much more information, configuration etc.

What releases the barrier, and when?

Do you want to propagate the exception(s) to the main thread?

What if multiple splits fail, etc, etc.

The general answer is sending a message with a `Throwable` payload to the barrier's `trigger` method will release the thread by throwing a `MessagingException` with the `Throwable` as its cause. The gateway unwraps the `MessagingException` and throws the cause (which is the original payload sent to the barrier's trigger method).

**EDIT**

I have added a [pull request to the barrier sample app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/pull/155) to show one technique of collecting exceptions on the async threads and causing the barrier to throw a consolidated exception back to the gateway caller.

Comment: Gary, I added the config. At the moment service releases the barrier...Yes the best would be to catch everything in the main thread. If one of the split fails ideally would be to stop others from execution, throw the exception and inform the barrier (main catch block).

Comment: See my edit - it's a bit more difficult to stop the other splits from processing (and causing the aggregator to release early) but the basic technique of sending the exceptions back to the caller is shown in the sample.

Comment: Works fine, so in more complicated setups - any exception thrown by the executors' threads will be send to the error-channel="errors"?
I have also a question to splitter - by default it has apply-sequence="true" - why you have <int:header-enricher> that extracts sequence details and correlationId in the chain for input-channel="errors" channel? Couldn't be the errors straight pass to the aggregator channel?

Comment: Correct; the `error-channel` will get all errors. However, the `ErrorMessage` sent to the channel is a new `Message<?>` with a payload of `MessagingException`. Since it's a new message, it doesn't inherit the headers from the failed message (there are important reasons for this, in other situations). Instead, the error message payload has two properties, the `failedMessage` and the `cause`. The header enricher before routing to the aggregator is effectively saying: "I want to aggregate this error message with other results (good or bad) for associated messages emitted by the splitter".